# Domain resolving problem

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, a-record

I have registered a new domain. I want to use it with my server. I have a static IP for my server. Using my registrar control panel I have added an A record for my domain.com with value IP of my server. When I look it up with using `http://www.hcidata.info/host2ip.htm` page to find the IP address which domain.com matches I can get the result as my IP adress but when I browse the domain.com it does not respond. What is the problem, how can i get rid of it?

Comment: I've just tried dig domain.com, host domain.com, and nslookup domain.com will get you started. all of them failed with no server by timeout

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to take a stab and say that you probably *just* set this up.  DNS takes time to propagate globally, anywhere from 24-72 hours.  If it's still doing it at that point, then check back in with us.

Comment: Thanks.. so why can the web page i've mentioned above return the IP address? I really wonder this is why i am asking.

Comment: It just depends on what DNS server it's querying.  DNS servers cache both positive and negative responses for hostnames, and store them for various amounts of time.  This is why it takes a generous amount of time for everything to even out.  If you're truly curious and want to know more about DNS, pick up [this book](http://www.amazon.com/DNS-BIND-5th-Cricket-Liu/dp/0596100574) and give it a read.  It has everything you could want to know about DNS in it.

Comment: Actually, you generally do not need to wait that long for propagation of a new domain.  A change to an existing DNS record may take a while to be fully switched due to TTL issues, but new records are generally quite fast.  Gone are the days of new .com domains taking up to 24 hours to be created due to zone generation only happening twice daily.

Comment: @Cakemox you're probably right, but it's definitely not instantaneous either.

Comment: @holo they changed the Root DNS servers refresh interval from 24 hours to ~2 hours a while back.

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to look up the domain and get your IP address on a third-party website, it may not be a DNS issue.  You should confirm resolution using `dig`, `host`, or `nslookup`.

If you created your DNS record without a `www`, make sure you are not trying to browse to `www.domain.com`.

Finally, is your web server running?  If you browse to the IP address, does it work?

Comment: Web server is running when i browse it with using IP address everything is fine. www issue is not the case i am sure about it. How can i confirm resolution using dig, host, nslookup? Could you explain a little bit more, please?

Comment: Do I need to do anything at the server side after specifying DNS records?

Comment: `dig domain.com`, `host domain.com`, or `nslookup domain.com` will get you started.

Comment: all of them failed with no server by timeout

Comment: Try `dig +trace domain.com` to see exactly where it is failing.

Answer (score 0):

If you've just created this domain, please wait 24-48 hours before starting any troubleshooting.  This is to allow the new entries in the root nameservers to be entered and picked up.  If you've had this domain for longer than 24-48 hours and you are still having trouble, post the domain name here and we'll sort it out for you straight away.